# Intercept set methods with Spring AOP to check values

Tags: spring-aop

Sorry my bad english.

I'm developing a system that will send XML data to another system.

To create the XML I'm using XStream, so I have created the classes that will be serialized to XML. But I need to check the size of attributes in the classes. I thought to do that in set() methods in the classes. But write a similar code on every class, in every set() method, is not good. So I thought I can use Spring AOP to do that.

I'm new to AOP and I just know that I can do that using it, but I don't know how.

Someone can help me?

Thanks a lot.